# Clion doesn't print to console

Tags: c, clion

I am using `printf("%d", 15);` and nothing prints on the console.

I tried calling `setvbuf (stdout, NULL, _IONBF, 0);` first, nothing changed.
Any ideas how to tackle this issue ?

Comment: Line buffering. printf("%d\n", 15);

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`printf` *buffers* the output. It will not *flush* the buffer (i.e. actually write out the contents) until a newline is reached.

The best remedy is to use `printf("%d\n", 15);`. Alternatively you can *flush* the buffer using `fflush(stdout);`

You can suppress the buffering behaviour by writing `setbuf(stdout, NULL);` but I wouldn't recommend your interfering with the workings in that way.

Answer (score 0):

Had same problem. This was solution for me when using **Clion**.

1. Use **debug option** when running program.

[image: debug button]

2. Use `fflush(stdout)`.

```c
printf("Test\n");
fflush(stdout);
```

After that you should see output in your **debug console**.